# Can I use different web.config file as per folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-config

I want to use Multiple web.config file.
But I want to use all web.config file as per different folder.
How can I use web.config file as per folder.

```
Project:
Folder 1: Test
Inside Folder web.config for Test Folder
Folder 2: Hello
Inside Folder web.config for Hello Folder
```

Comment: When you deploy the application the folders structure will have to be the used as where you build.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, IIS doesn't allow multiple web.config files to exist in web applications. In this case, try nested Web.config

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390723/web-config-in-nested-folder